# Try command with time interval until it returns true, and from that run another command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the following code:

```
SET ProcessorUsage = wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process get Name,PercentProcessorTime | findstr /i /c:chrome
if %ProcessorUsage% LSS 2 (taskkill /f /im chrome.exe)
```

Basically this script terminates `Chrome` if it identifies that the processor usage is less than 2%.

From this, I would like to know how I can make the script check the processor usage every 2 seconds and when it returns `True` it ends `Chrome` and closes the `CMD` window.

I found some things like this:

```
until YOURCOMMAND; do echo "Retrying"; sleep 2; done
```

But I couldn't make it work.

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Your `set` command is wrong. It should be ```SET "ProcessorUsage=wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process get Name, PercentProcessorTime | findstr /i "chrome""```. Currently you've created a variable, ```%ProcessorUsage %```.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```bash
:Loop
@%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Path^
 Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process Where^
 "Name Like 'chrome%%' And PercentProcessorTime >= 2" Get PercentProcessorTime^
 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "[0123456789]" 1>NUL && (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome*" /T) || (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 /NoBreak 1>NUL & GoTo Loop)
```

*Please do not deliberately use the `/F` option, (omitted above), with `taskkill.exe`, until a graceful termination has already failed.*

Comment: Right! As I am a beginner, I confess that I am a little confused about how it works, but it seems to do what i need. Now, if I wanted to use this same logic, but instead of `taskkill`, run these 2 commands: `for /f "delims=" %%X in ('dir /s/b/ad Proxy') do for /f "delims=" %%Y in ('dir /s/b/a-d "%%X"') do move "%%Y" ".\03. Proxy"` and `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s/b/ad Proxy') do rd "%%i"`. How would that look?

Comment: It would be something like this: `:Loop
@%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Path^
 Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process Where^
 "Name Like 'chrome%%' And PercentProcessorTime >= 2" Get PercentProcessorTime^
 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "[0123456789]" 1>NUL && (
    for /f "delims=" %%X in ('dir /s/b/ad Proxy') do for /f "delims=" %%Y in ('dir /s/b/a-d "%%X"') do move "%%Y" ".\03. Proxy") && (
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s/b/ad Proxy') do rd "%%i") || (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 /NoBreak 1>NUL & GoTo Loop)` ?

Comment: I did some tests with `taskkill`, but it is not looping until `PercentProcessorTime` is `>=2`, apparently it tries once, waits 2 seconds and just tries one more time.