# Keep trying a command until it returns "True" and then execute another

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, ffmpeg, command-prompt

I'm trying to make a script to check the processor usage for a specific process every **10 seconds**, and when the usage is `less than 2%` I want another 2 commands to be executed.

The purpose is to know when the program has finished processing the requests, in order to release the execution of the other commands.

I created this script to check the processor usage by this application:

```
SET ProcessorUsage = wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process get Name,PercentProcessorTime | findstr /i /c:RenderQuery

%ProcessorUsage%
```

And these are the commands I want to be executed when the processor usage of the `RenderQuery` application is `less than 2%`:

```
for /f "delims=" %%X in ('dir /s/b/ad Proxy') do for /f "delims=" %%Y in ('dir /s/b/a-d "%%X"') do move "%%Y" ".\03. Proxy"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s/b/ad Proxy') do rd "%%i"
```

I tried to create a script that way here:

```
SET ProcessorUsage = wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process get Name,PercentProcessorTime | findstr /i /c:RenderQuery
:Loop
IF %ProcessorUsage% LSS 2 (
(for /f "delims=" %%X in ('dir /s/b/ad Proxy') do for /f "delims=" %%Y in ('dir /s/b/a-d "%%X"') do move "%%Y" ".\03. Proxy") && (for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s/b/ad Proxy') do rd "%%i")
) ELSE (
sleep 10 && goto Loop
)
```

I also tried this way here:

```
SET ProcessorUsage = wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process get Name,PercentProcessorTime | findstr /i /c:RenderQuery

:Loop
for %ProcessorUsage% LSS 2 do (
(for /f "delims=" %%X in ('dir /s/b/ad Proxy') do for /f "delims=" %%Y in ('dir /s/b/a-d "%%X"') do move "%%Y" ".\03. Proxy") && (for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s/b/ad Proxy') do rd "%%i") || (sleep 10 && goto Loop)
)
```

With these scripts I tried to create the window that only blinks and closes right away...

What's the best way to do this?

**EDIT**

**Explaining in more detail:** I work with video production, so I constantly need to render **Proxy** files, which are video files with low quality to be used during my video editing and replaced at the end of editing, this makes the much smoother video editing.

Having said that, I have a **folder model**, inside this folder model there is a folder where I always download the video files from the camera and in that folder there is always a `.bat` file that opens all the video files in the software that generates **proxy** files of the camera's video files.

This `.bat` file has this exact code:

```
start "" "C:\Users\User\Downloads\FFmpeg_Batch_AV_Converter_Portable_2.8.4_x64\FFBatch.exe" -f "%~dp0\"
```

When this software opens, it automatically renders the **proxy** files and their output is always in a **child folder of the original files folder**, and the name of the folder is **Proxy**.

The issue is that I don't want them to be in several separate **Proxy** folders, so I created another `.bat` file that is in the parent folder of all video files, this script contains exactly these lines:

```
for /f "delims=" %%X in ('dir /s/b/ad Proxy') do for /f "delims=" %%Y in ('dir /s/b/a-d "%%X"') do move "%%Y" ".\03. Proxy"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s/b/ad Proxy') do rd "%%i"
```

That is, it only searches **recursively** for files that are inside folders named **Proxy**, then it moves these files to the folder **03. Proxy** that is inside the parent folder.

The second line looks for all proxy folders (which are now empty) and deletes them.

The point is: I currently run the second script manually, as soon as the render finishes, and I would like it to run automatically.

Given this, I thought of adding a line in the first script, which opens the video files in the rendering program, this line would call the second script in the background, and the second script would be analyzing the CPU usage of this application every 10 seconds, and when the usage is less than 2% (in theory there is nothing else rendering, since it has a low CPU usage) it executes the lines that move the files and remove the folders.

I think there's a good change for this to work, because this software renders 4 videos at a time, and this means that there is no time between stopping rendering a video and starting another... the CPU usage is always very high until all the videos are finished, so I think this would be the best signal to release the other commands.

Comment: Please note, that the OP has already asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75012962), just using different applications, and conditional commands, and received answers.

Comment: However, the answer was not conclusive...

Comment: The answer was conclusive, it was simply the parameters which were changed!

Comment: If you pay attention to the later comments and test the code, you will see that it doesn't work as expected, it tries and stops the execution, which is not useful to solve the problem.

Comment: It's not possible for me to test the code, not only do I not use Windows, but if I did I wouldn't use a Google product ever. That said, the methodology I offeed is sound, the programs, parameters, timings and permissions, are impossible for me to diagnose for you. There is nothing in my methodology which should cause the loop to end after just one iteration.

Comment: I understand, but the code is not working, I copied it exactly the way you formulated it, it tries, sleeps, and stops. I am very grateful for your help, the issue is that I have been trying to get this to work for days and it is something that is really blocking my workflow, so I need to solve it, I am struggling for this, spending hours and hours applying tests... so all that's left is to ask and hope someone has an alternative.

Comment: Well if you tell everyone which process you are really trying to measure, information about it, and exactly what you are trying to achieve based upon that measurement, complete with accurate timings, and introduce some reasonable debugging, perhaps that can be done. However, as it stands you've offered us none of that.

Comment: I'm trying to check when a rendering program finishes rendering the videos and based on that copy them to another folder and remove the empty folders that are left. That's just it... that's why I'm using the CPU measurement, since the CPU usage is practically at 100% until the end of rendering all the files.

Comment: I doubt that the WMI query you are using is even useful for the task you're wanting to perform. The percentage processor time is very likely calculated over a period using multiple data points, and not a true reflection of the current CPU usage of a single, or often multiple, cores. You are probably better off looking at the verbose output from `tasklist.exe`.

Comment: Right, I really have little knowledge in CMD, I'm a beginner... I know how to do what I need in Powershell, but I would like to solve it in a .bat file for the simplicity of execution and because I would like to learn. I really don't have much idea if it will work, but I'm trying everything that comes to mind... so if you can explain me a better way, I'll be very grateful and I'll be happy to mark your answer as a resolution.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the working PowerShell code, and perhaps, we'd have a better idea of your exact task, as well as trying to determine if it can be translated. You should also explain why specifically you aren't using that working PowerShell based code.

Comment: I added the FFmpeg tag because after this post was edited it was clear that the asker would be better off building a script solving their workflow using FFmpeg to replace their existing rendering tool FFmpeg Batch AV Converter and a bodge of trying to watch the CPU usage. I am no expert in FFmpeg but I am sure someone on this site is and might be able to provide advice on how to use it in a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more testing and created a `Powershell` script that does what I need.

In these tests that I did, I realized that the `FFBatch` process does not consume CPU, in fact it opens instances of `ffmpeg.exe` and those do consume CPU, but with that I could see something even more interesting, at the end of the process the instances of `ffmpeg.exe` are closed and this can be a signal to move on to the next code.

With that in mind, I set up a script in `Powershell` like this:

```
# This pause at the beginning is to wait until ffmpeg is open, otherwise the variable will be null
Start-Sleep 10
            
Do{
$ffmpeg = Get-Process ffmpeg -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Write-Host "test"
Start-Sleep 2
            
}until([bool] $ffmpeg -eq $false)
Write-Host "Works!"
```

This works flawlessly, and I believe it's better than using CPU utilization, as pointed out several times here.

**The question now is:** is it possible to convert this to a `.bat`?

I really would like use a `.bat` because all the other scripts are in `CMD`, besides, `.bat` files are a bit easier to run than Powershell scripts.

Comment: Remembering, the idea is to keep the first script that opens the files inside `FFmpeg Batch` application, and add a line like: `START /MIN CMD.EXE /C Move Files.bat`

Comment: `Move Files.bat` would run the check function to move the files once the `ffmpeg.exe` process is no longer running.
I know it may seem a little strange that I want to do this in 2 scripts instead of all in 1, but this is how I can make this verification process run in 2 plane, without a command prompt window open.

Comment: It might be a better idea for you to have a bat file that then runs this PowerShell script. To do this from batch-file you need it to contain the command `powershell -file PSFILENAME.ps` but replace `PSFILENAME.ps` with your script file.

Comment: This is exactly what you should be doing. Good job.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention and help, Ryan!

I ended up converting the entire second script to `PowerShell` and now it's working perfectly.
I just added the `-windowstyle hidden` argument to your code, as I want the `PowerShell` script to run in the background.

Comment: It was no problem. Do mark your answer with the PowerShell script as the answer. This will make things easer for the next person with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the scripts causing the command window to blink and close instantly you can run the scripts from the command prompt and the output will stay on screen. This might be helpful for you to see what is going wrong with your current script.

From you question it looks like you are trying to do some kind of secondary operation when RenderQuery is finished processing those requests.

It look like they way you are doing this is by watching the execution of RenderQuery and waiting until it is sleeping and then doing some kind of file operation.

Be advised that threads can sleep for many reasons other than being finished with a operation. A thread could be sleeping because a higher priority thread is running or because it needs to access a memory page from disk. Because of this using the CPU usage of a process is not a reliable way to tell if it is done.

The best way to do this for a given process is dependent on that specific application. For this answer I am giving a generic solution.

The ideal way to trigger a secondary operation when a process finishes a request is by having the process itself signal that it is finished with a task or having it start running the secondary operation. If the process does not support this and can not be modified to support this then this is not a option.

A second safe way is to check for the existence of specific signs that the process is complete on the system. A good example of a possible sign like this is the presence of a file of a specific minimum size on the file system that only exists larger than that size when the initial task is completed. If the size of such a file when completed is unknown then another option is to check for the presence of specific signatures in the file (Like seeing if it is a valid PNG image). Once the signature is detected you can start the secondary operation.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I understand that point, but in several tests I've seen that the CPU utilization only really goes below 2% when the program completes the requests, that's because it's a multithreaded rendering software, that's why this It's the most accurate methodology I've found so far. When the option of the software itself triggers the actions, it is something out of reach since it is not an open source program...

Comment: 2 follow up questions:

Q1: Did you get anything of value from running your script from the command line? I am wondering if it gave any errors or showed any control flow issues.

Q2: If I understand this correctly it looks like you are trying to move files after the process finishes. Do this files have any signatures of interest. For example are the files bigger than 0 bytes or are the files valid images. If yes then it might be worth it to check the files and if they are valid move them. If you can share any info about the output files I might know how to check them.

Comment: A1: I didn't get any errors, what happens is that if I use the script in a .bat file the window flashes and closes, and if I use it directly in a command prompt window the script runs, it makes the sleep command of 10 seconds and then stops, reappearing the folder where the window is open to type a new command.
A2: As far as I could analyze, I didn't find any signature of interest that I could use, I constantly use this method in other scripts, but in this case I couldn't find anything that would indicate that the rendering process was finished, so I resorted to CPU usage.

Comment: ON1: That means that there is a issue with your flow control. The only difference between running in command line vs in explore is for command line the output stays on screen. This means your script is not looping or might have crashed for some reason.

Comment: ON2: Can you move the file before the rendering is done? If you get a error when you attempt to move it then your signature can be the presence of a lock on the file until the rendering is done.

Comment: I've edited my question and added more details of the process, when you can, see if it's a little clearer what I'm trying to do. Thanks a lot for all the help so far!

Comment: I see you are making proxies using a application built around [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/). It might be a better idea to build a script for your specific workflow using ffmpeg directly and not using FFmpeg Batch AV Converter with a bodge. It looks like FFmpeg Batch AV Converter generates a command to send to FFmpeg. If you run the FFmpeg directly in a script in a blocking way followed by your file move commands this might do exactly what you need.

Comment: In this regard, I would really like to use the application, I used ffmpeg in code for a long time, but this application is really extremely useful, it takes the use of ffmpeg to another level and in a very simple and fast way. Another point is that in this software I can see a preview of the rendering and the remaining time until the complete completion of the process, using ffmpeg in code I would need to develop a lot to have something close to that.